# Let me assume two firewall are connected in active -active mode ,how load sharing happen among two

Tags: firewall

i wants to know when two firewalls are connected in active -active mode for example A1 and A2 are connected in active -active . if session is initiated from A1 reverse traffic of this session will come to A1 or A2 firewall . And what are possibilities coming reverse traffic of same session traffic on another active firewall .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In active-active mode, usually each firewall has its own virtual addresses. If one of the firewalls fails the other takes over its virtual address.

Without further mechanisms, this breaks currently running connections (sessions). Some concepts use session sharing to avoid this.